# users access in Lotus Notes Database

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a lotus notes database. I want to give a user right access to a particular user. Is there any way to set the database and then the user will access all the forms and views? or I need it to set one by one to give the user an access?

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Notes has a few security points.  First is access to the server itself, and that is controlled within the Domino Directory under the Server document.

Next is the Database ACL (Access Control Lists).  There you can control who has access to the database at a macro-level.  You can specify, for example, that a person has read-only access or editor access, etc.

The next more granular level is the Document or View itself.  A designer can create reader or author items in the documents and views to control who can read or edit the documents, or open the views.

Most of the time you'll be working at the Database ACL level.